# PPTP: Allow remote clients to communicate with each other

Tags: centos, iptables, vpn, pptp

I have a PPTP server. Clients log in to the server, but can not ping each other. The clients are at different locations.

The problem is with my IPTABLES forward chain ....
here is my iptables:

[iptables](https://www.dropbox.com/s/45orlr4xzz1cw00/iptables.rules)

Answer (score 1):

in my case in centOs 6.7 i use this iptables rules:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -i ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/service iptables save
```

where **192.168.0.0/24** is your private ip for clients and make sure your interface name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowing only icmp types 0,3,8,11 
Try to remove them and allow all with

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

If it works, then start over and adjust the icmp types you want to pass.